# Problems with Positioning and responsiveness

Tags: html, css, position, responsive, display

could you please help me to make my html responsive and help me with the positioning of my items? I will send you below a picture of how I would like my screen to look like

Picture of how i Want

[image]

I am having problems with display grid,flex, position absolute, my screen looks like this:

Picute of how it is

[image]

It even looks responsive, but when I try to view it on other devices it is totally broken.

Here is the HTML of how I created the divs and put the icons in svg, is it the right way?

```
    <div class="primaryinformations">

        <img src="example.png">

        <img id="trash" src="icons/trash.svg">

        <img id="edit" src="icons/edit.svg">

        <h1>Quirk, o Quokka</h1>

        <img id="tennis" src="icons/tennis.svg">

        <img id="medkit" src="icons/medkit.svg">

    </div>


    <div class="secondaryinformations">

        <img src="icons/dna.svg">

        <h4>Raça </h4>


        <h3>Setonyx Brachyurus</h3>

        <img src="icons/gender.svg">

        <h4>Sexo </h4>

        <h3>Macho</h3>

        <img src="icons/birthday.svg">

        <h4>Data de Nascimento</h4>

        <h3>17/07/2021</h3>

        <img src="icons/pill.svg">

        <h4>Fichas de Medicamento em Andamento</h4>

        <h3>2 Medicações em Andamento</h3>

        <img src="icons/tennis.svg">

        <h4>Atividades em Andamento</h4>

        <h3>3 Atividades em Andamento</h3>

    </div>
```

Here is my CSS :

.primaryinformations img{

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

.primaryinformations h1{

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

}

.primaryinformations #trash{

```
padding-left: 85vw;
position: absolute;
top: 15vw;
```

}

.primaryinformations #edit{

```
padding-left: 80vw;
position: absolute;
top: 60vw;
```

}

.primaryinformations #tennis{

```
padding-left: 33vw;
position: absolute;
top: 90vw;
```

}

.primaryinformations #medkit{

```
padding-left: 55vw;
position: absolute;
top: 90vw;
```

}

.secondaryinformations {

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
padding-top: 25%;
```

The Navbar I will try to fix in a future change.

I don't know if it is done in the most correct way possible, could you help me fix these problems and point me to study sources for responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

**flexbox**:
You need a flex container to set your properties properly, we call flex container the **parent element** and flex items their **children**. After this, you need some modifications to your HTML.

```
     <div class="secondaryinformations">
    
           <article class="flex-container">
            <img src="icons/dna.svg">
            <div class="flex-container flex-column">
              <h4>Raça </h4>
              <h3>Setonyx Brachyurus</h3>
            </div>
          </article>
    
          <article class="flex-container">
            <img src="icons/gender.svg">
            <div class="flex-container flex-column">
              <h4>Sexo </h4>
              <h3>Macho</h3>
            </div>
          </article>
    
          <article class="flex-container">
            <img src="icons/birthday.svg">           

            <div class="flex-container flex-column">
               <h4>Data de Nascimento</h4>
               <h3>17/07/2021</h3>
            </div>
          </article>
    
        </div>
```

And then your css could be easily manipulated in the flexbox pattern

```
.flex-container{
    display:flex;
 }
.flex-column{
   flex-direction:column;
}
```

About the responsivity, you could read some infos about @mediaquery [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), it changes a lot the way you will implement because depends on what final result you want to reach.